# There is any way to do a subitem from subitem from expandablelistview?

Tags: string, listview, expandablelistview, subitem

There is any way to do a subitem from subitem from expandablelistview? 
if yes tell me how... her is my try to do this...(do a third subitem..). And more two updates from my code...

```
private Context context;
String [] things = {"sushi", "tells", "foods", "kids", "ice cream", "songs", "fun", "bar"};
String [][] subthings = {
        {"without fish"},
        {"teel me baby},
        {"eat", "non eat", "i love"},
        {"Burguer King", "Mc Donalds", "Willians foods"},
        {"whithout chocolate", "chocolate"},
        {"Sweet Child o mine"},
        {"kids"},
        {"cachaça", "milkshake"},
};
String [][][] subsubthings = {          //haha subsubsubthings
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {"sushi", "chocolate"},

        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
};
```

add another part of my code..

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    robot = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    TextView text = new TextView(context);
    texto.setText(title[groupPosition]);
    texto.setTypeface(robot);
    texto.setTextSize(20);
    texto.setPadding(70, 30, 0, 30);
    texto.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);


    return texto;
}
```

and more..

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    robot = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"); 
    TextView text = new TextView(context);
    text.setText(subthings[groupPosition][childPosition]);
    text.setTypeface(robot);
    text.setTextSize(15);
    text.setPadding(90, 20, 0, 20);






    return text;
}
```

Comment: are you looking for UI sample code for having subitem in subitem of Expandablelist or data structure to store such kind of data?

Comment: only UI simple code.. (i think) in future set on titles on Expandablelist toggle buttons and in all subitens set clickable understand?

Comment: create a custom adapter for expandable list,In GetView method of parent Adapter, instead of creating a simple view, inflate another list view and assign child adapter to it. I haven't tested it. Try and let me know.

Comment: I can't imagine that..sorry..can you write a simple example code for this? Instead of creating a simple view..inflate another view assign child adapter? because I learn to do a expandable listview parent and child with textviews...i will update my question and look after please

Comment: sorry, i was supposed to write "getChildView" not getView. paste your getChildView and also adapter which is to be displayed as a grandchild. i will help with integrating grandchild list items in child item view creation.

Comment: it's there man! I dont have other adapter, only this.. and I did the "subsubthings" only for example of what I want. I need to do other ListView? Thanks in advance man!

Comment: and if yes, i need to do a listview in MainActivity or in my adapter?

Comment: Create an Expandable list and adpater for it, create another normal list and adapter. In GetChildView() of adpater you are supposed to return a view, all you have to do is make sure this view is a "normal list" which is created by inflating normal list which u had prepared earlier...

Comment: I give up harshal. I cant here.. searching in others foruns, i saw isnt possible to do it..expandable into expandable or listview into expandable.. but i guess that is possible and im doing anything wrong..

Comment: i am busy with exams until next week end, will update once i do the experiment... for now try this: your first level list will be series of dynamically created text view in a pain scroll view. on click of this text view you create a dynamic list view and add that below the text view... so it would look like a two level list view